# Do event handlers need to exactly match the event signature?

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, event-handling

I would like to do something like the following:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Event Evt1(ByVal c As c1)
    Public Event Evt2(ByVal c As c2)

    Private Sub OnEvt1OrEvt2(ByVal c As c1) Handles Me.Evt1, Me.Evt2
    End Sub 
End Class

Public Class c1
End Class

Public Class c2
    Inherits c1
End Class
```

However, it seems to be invalid syntax, as the signature of OnEvt1OrEvt2 doesn't match that of Evt2.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edit:** The above code seems to work fine for everyone but me, but it doesn't compile for me in VS2005 SP1.

The error message is something like:

> Error BC31029: The method 'Private Sub OnEvt1OrEvt2(c As
>   WindowsApplication1.c1)' can not handle
>   the event 'Public Event Evt2(c As
>   WindowsApplication1.c2)' because the
>   signatures do not match.

**Edit 2:**

> I have found this in msdn, 
>   vb-related:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx
>
> The code in the Form Load assigns
>   values to the Name property of the
>   three Bucket objects. It also calls
>   AddHandler to direct all of the
>   Overflowing events to the
>   HandleOverflow procedure. As you can
>   see, a single event handler can handle
>   multiple events, as long as all of the
>   events have **compatible** argument lists.
>
> (...)
>
> Copyright © 2002 Informant
>   Communications Group and Microsoft
>   Corporation

(Emphasis mine)

No word about what two "compatible argument lists" exactly are, though.

**Edit 3:**

OK, I found it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vb9overview_topic10

> Relaxed Delegates
>
> When creating a delegate using
>   AddressOf or Handles in Visual Basic
>   8.0, one of the methods targeted for binding to the delegate identifier
>   must exactly match the signature of
>   the delegate's type.

It was added in VB9.

Comment: Basically the "compatible argument lists" means that each parameter type in the method signature has to be the same type as the corresponding parameter in the delegate declaration, or there has to be a *reference conversion* (one which maintains representational identity) from the delegate's parameter type to the method's parameter type.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That's what I thought; any sources for that definition?

Comment: The C# language specification gives details, and I'm sure they'd be equivalent for a version of VB which supports this. I don't have a reference on me right now, but I could look it up later if you want.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I don't think that's neccessary. I'll trust your word :-) I think I have a copy of the C# specs at home, I will take a look at it (although it's quite old, a pre-1.0 book). Thank you very much, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you would need to define your event such that the parameter is passed as type Object, and then perform a casting operation within the event handler.

OR you could define an interface common to both C1 and C2, and use that as the parameter. You could then either use the reference "as-is" if the methods defined on the interface are suitable, or you would once again find yourself performing a casting operation.

Note that if you define an interface with the common methods, and if these common methods are all that is required for use by the event handler, then you do not need to perform any sort of "TypeOf" determination in order to handle the event.

All that said, I know that it is best, if possible, to follow the Event signature standard established within .NET wherever possible:

```
Public Event SomethingHappened(ByVal Sender as Object, byVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

It looks to me like you might create a class (or classes) which inherits from System.EventArgs, and then define a custom property to access your custom parameter. This way, you can still pass a reference to the client object in the `Sender` parameter, and then access your custom parameter thus:

```
Public Class MyCustomEventArgs
    Inherits System.EventArgs

    Private _MyCustomInterface As ICustomInterface

    Public Property Myproperty As ICustomInterface
        Get As ICustomInterface
            Return _MyCustomInterface
        End Get
        Let(ByVal value As ICustomInterface)
            _MyCustomInterface = value
        End Let
    End Property
End Class

Public Sub HandleMyEvent(ByVal Sender As Object, byVal e As MyCustomEventArgs) Handles MyEvent
    Dim MyCustom Interface As ICustomInterface
    MyCustominterface = e.TheCustominterface
    MyCustominterface.DoSomething
End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't really solve my problem (which really is a non-issue, as SoMoS and yodaj007 pointed out), but I think it answers the question, so I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles for me, from the command line.

I don't know when the feature appeared in VB, but in C# this was one of the differences between C# 1 and C# 2. Delegates can be created from methods with *compatible* signatures rather than requiring an *exact* match.

EDIT: Given your question edit, it looks like this is an issue with VB8 / VS2005. It works for me with both the VS2008 and VS2010 compilers (VB9 and VB10 respectively).

Comment: @Jaime: Aha, you're using VS 2005. I wonder whether it turns out it's a new feature in VB9...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a C# user and am a lousy VB.NET-reader. Automatic online conversion utilities failed to help me with your code, so I'm writing from scratch. There are two thoughts that I would like to implement at every event invocation I see:

1. Use EventHandler<T> instead of declaring custom delegates.
2. Have your base class derive from EventArgs:

   ```
   public static void Main() {
       BaseEvent += OnSomething;
       DerivedEvent += OnSomething;
   }

   public static void OnSomething(Object sender, MyBase args) {
       // Awesome!
   }

   public static event EventHandler<MyBase> BaseEvent;
   public static event EventHandler<MyDerived> DerivedEvent;

   public class MyBase : EventArgs {}
   public class MyDerived : MyBase {}
   ```

   }

After actually creating a VB.NET console application to try this out, I found out that just removing your "..." in your code compiles, so you basically have a working code snippet already... What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't compile in vs2005. Says: "Method 'Private Sub OnEvt1OrEvt2(c As WindowsApplication1.c1)' can't handle the event 'Public Event Evt2(c As WindowsApplication1.c2)' because the signatures do not match".

Comment: BTW I had already tried to add the event handlers with AddHandler (that's the vb way), and no luck, either. But thanks anyway.